# How to install python modules for specific python version

Tags: python, installation

I needed to install UCS2 python next to UCS4 python. So I went to comp.lang.python and asked them about it. Probably not the best place to ask it, but they answered

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.python/bGuAfqa76W8

and now i have brand new python 2.7.3 ucs2 installed in /opt/bin/python

What I need now is - how can I install all other python modules that I have installed for that python version also. Basically stuff like PIL and postgresql and mod_wsgi - basically everything needed to run Django for that python version.

Is this the right the place to ask for it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use virtualenv otherwise all installations would go to default installed python.

What virtualenv will do is install multiple python versions having separate installed modules on the system and you can choose to run any version anytime you want. It's the default way of python world to manage different versions.

Also install [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=virtualenvwrapper&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CGMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.doughellmann.com%2Fprojects%2Fvirtualenvwrapper%2F&ei=6n3fT4OALMK8rAe3_amqDQ&usg=AFQjCNGDff9RD485NNdUy31ERqpD9r25qg) which simplifies usage of virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is probably to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org) with the `--python` parameter to specify your custom installation. Then install the modules you want using `easy_install` or `pip`.

The Right Way is to build Debs/RPMs for all the modules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have nice and clear guide where/how to get started. Do i also need to get rid of this UCS2 python installation and install it again?

Comment: Ok. ive installed virtualenv and it looks like i dont understand the results. When i run the activate script - then i get correct python version. but when i run this activate_this.py in django.wsgi script, then the python version i get is not the one of virtual environment. Whats up with that?

Answer (score 0):

1st. in your origin system generate a report like that: pip freeze > requirements.txt

2nd. in your new destination execute pip reading the report generated, like this: 
pip install -r requirements.txt

In this way pip will install the exacly version you have previosuly installed.